# CSS highlight menu

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to get the active CSS drop-down menu header to change colour when it has been selected. At the moment it changes when you hover over it but I would like it to stay highlighted when you click on it or select an item from it's menu.

My html is below (all within div id="menu"):

```
<html>

<div id="menuspacer">  

<ul class="drop">

<li><a href="/services" class="active">Services</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="/services/1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/2">2</a></li>    
            <li><a href="/services/3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/services/4">4</a></li>


        </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="/products" class="active">Products</a>  

    <ul>
            <li><a href="/products/1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products/4">4</a></li>

        </ul>

</li>

<li><a href="/contact" class="active">Contact</a></li>      

</ul>

</div id="menuspacer">  

</html>
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
#menu { margin: 0 auto; padding:0px; text-align:center; vertical-align: top; } 

#menuspacer {position: relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 auto; vertical-align: top; }

ul.drop a {color: #fff; font: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-decoration: none; display:block;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #fff; background: #555; color: #fff;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; }
ul.drop li { text-align:left; position:relative;  padding: 8px 20px; float:left;}
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #1e7c9a;}
ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 150px; background: #555; border: 2px solid #000;  }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }
```

The menu is working fine but I can't figure out how to use a.active to keep the menu highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/wBtXP/

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by 'Keep the menu highlighted' - right now clicking a link just navigates away from the page.

Comment: Maybe you should just add a class for the next page desired active menu item in the back-end. Or will you add further javascript behaviour for page loading?

Comment: `#menuspacer ul.drop li.active { background-color: red; }` and add a class active to the top menu <li> you want active (using current page)

Answer (score 0):

Active pseudo class doesn't work like that, it means what happens the moment you click on the button. In order to make the desired effect create a new class that has the exact same properties as the hover one does. And asign it to a different button on every website.

Answer (score -1):

give the li of your top menu item services an id of stay

```
#stay:hover { background: blue; }
```

change to whatever background/color you want obviously, and then do the same thing for the other menu items with a different ID

you want to give the li's of the top main menu items an ID because when you hover over the submenus you are still actually hovering over that specific li